# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: null [90028-200]

Tags: h2, h2db

My h2db version is h2-1.4.200.
the database started few times ago,reboot the database but cannot connected!
The problem is:

IO Exception: null [90028-200] 90028/90028 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: null [90028-200]

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!!

Comment: any info append :
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from file nio:D:/Smart/deploy/packinstall/Release/test12/framework_manager/LightingBUSHDB/data/h2dbdata.mv.db failed at 3205744 (length 2056192), read 0, remaining 512 [1.4.200/1] 
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.readFully(DataUtils.java:456) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.readFully(FileStore.java:98)

Comment: at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)